# How to create a small dataset to test my CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

I recently implemented a CNN (using Tensorflow Python API) and I tested it with MNIST dataset.

Now i would like to test it with bigger images (like 100x100p pixels).

To do so I am using scikit-learn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d like this just to get N (here equals 10) images :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

HowManyPatches = 10

img = Image.open('./bulldog.jpeg')
imgarray = np.array(img)

patches = image.extract_patches_2d(imgarray, (100, 100), HowManyPatches)

for i in range(HowManyPatches):
    imgpatch = Image.fromarray(patches[i], 'RGB')
    name = 'patch_' + str(i) + '.jpeg'
    imgpatch.save(name)
```

So now i would like to put a (random since it is just to test the training time) label on every single patch i get.

I noticed that MNIST dataset is extracted from this kind of files : t10k-images.idx3-ubyte which seem to be an unknown type. So I would like to know how, once i succesfully put a label on my images, can i create this kind of files ?

To sum up the two main questions are :
How ta put a label on my images ?
How to get a dataset that i can use like MNIST dataset ? Or maybe there is a simpler way of creating a dataset differently from MNIST dataset ?

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to test training time and don't care about actual classification, you can use this:

```
x_pattern = np.array([[1 for i in range(100)] for i in range(100)])
x_train = np.array([x_pattern for i in range(100)])
y_train = np.array([1 if i % 2 == 0 else 2 for i in range(100)])
```

This will give you 100 samples of all white 100x100 images and alternating labels of 1, 0.

And if you already have 100x100 patches, you can just set range in the y_train line above to equal the number of patches you have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply !
Do you have any idea about the format of these .idx3(or 1)-ubyte files that are used for MNIST dataset ?

Comment: I do not know about the format of the file.  Are you getting it from the tensorflow datasets?  If that is the case, I assume it's has to do with how TF packages the data.  You shouldn't need to use that file format for anything you're doing.  If you want, you can just save the created images as PNG, JPEG, etc. using PIL.